# Other alternatives to achieve LIMIT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, datatable

I have created an SQL query to get certain data with LIMIT so I can use it in datatable. It has 76288 rows.

```
SELECT TransDate, AgentName, OfficeCode, year, ControlNumber, 
       ContainerNumber, BookingNumber, SealNumber, VesselName, ShippingLine, ShippingDate
FROM (
       SELECT a.TransDate, a.AgentName, a.OfficeCode, DATEPART(YEAR, a.TransDate) AS year, 
              a.ControlNumber, b.ContainerNumber, b.BookingNumber,
              b.SealNumber, b.VesselName, b.ShippingLine, b.ShippingDate,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.TransDate) R
       FROM Cargo_Transactions a 
       JOIN Cargo_Vessels b ON a.ControlNumber = b.ControlNumber 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [Routes] c ON a.RouteID = c.RouteID
       WHERE 
              a.TransDate IS NOT NULL 
              AND a.TransDate <= GETDATE() 
              AND DATEPART(YEAR, a.TransDate) = '2018'
) as f WHERE R BETWEEN 0 and 100
ORDER BY TransDate ASC;
```

0 and 100 is inside a variable that changes when the pagination is clicked.

If it's for the first hundred pages, it loads okay. But when I click the last page, it breaks saying timeout exceeded. Also, when I use the search function of the datatable, it's not working the way it should.

Example: I searched for `dino` in the datatable, it will say it has 95 records but will only show 1 record since the query is only between 0 and 10.

```
SELECT TransDate, AgentName, OfficeCode, year, ControlNumber, ContainerNumber, 
       BookingNumber, SealNumber, VesselName, ShippingLine, ShippingDate
FROM (
       SELECT a.TransDate, a.AgentName, a.OfficeCode, DATEPART(YEAR, a.TransDate) AS year, 
              a.ControlNumber, b.ContainerNumber, b.BookingNumber, b.SealNumber, 
              b.VesselName, b.ShippingLine, b.ShippingDate,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.TransDate) R
       FROM Cargo_Transactions a 
       JOIN Cargo_Vessels b ON a.ControlNumber = b.ControlNumber 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [Routes] c ON a.RouteID = c.RouteID
       WHERE 
              a.TransDate IS NOT NULL 
              AND a.TransDate <= GETDATE() 
              AND DATEPART(YEAR, a.TransDate) = '2018'
) as f WHERE R BETWEEN 0 and 10 AND AgentName LIKE '%dino%'
ORDER BY TransDate ASC;
```

I also tried `TOP` and `EXCEPT` but when I search for `SELECT TOP 0... EXCEPT SELECT TOP 100...` but it's only showing 9 rows.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to make it work by including the WHERE clause in the subquery. My only problem now is the `ORDER BY`. It only works in the current page shown which is data 1 - 10 but not for all the data.

Any alternatives? Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For starters, specify a date range rather than apply `DATEPART` to the column to allow an index on the column to be used more efficiently: `AND a.TransDate >='20180101' AND a.TrasnDate < '20190101'`. In SQL Server 2012 and later, you could try [`ORDER BY...OFFSET...FETCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql).

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks. I used `DATEPART` because I only need the year and not the specific date. We are also using an earlier version of SQL Server.

Comment: Please read this: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset  It applies to your way of using `ROW_NUMBER` and `WHERE` too.

Comment: The refactored expression will only return data for that year, and allow the index to be used.

Comment: move your row_numer outside of the sub-query, then you only need to compute it on selected records, and if there are only 95 records, you will only get rows 1-95.  You could still select on it by wrapping the whole query in another SELECT query